# How to extract a subset of a tuple in a new tuple?

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains a tuple of variable types such as this:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct Tester
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> t;

    template<class... T2s>
    std::tuple<T2s...> Get() { ??? }
};
```

An example instance is `Tester<int, float, char>`

I want my Get function to return only a subset of the inner tuple. For example, `tester.Get<int, char>` will return a `std::tuple<int, char>` whose values are copied from the appropriate members of the inner tuple.

You can assume that each type appears a maximum of once in a tuple and that `Get` will only be called with sensible template parameters that are in the tuple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, this is easier than you think. `std::get` takes a type, as an alternative to the tuple member index (since C++14), and returns the first matching type from the tuple:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class... Ts>
struct Tester
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> t;

    template<class... T2s>
    std::tuple<T2s...> Get() {
        return std::tuple<T2s...> {std::get<T2s>(t)...};
    }
};


int main()
{
    Tester<int, char, float> t;

    t.t=std::make_tuple(0,1,2);

    auto result=t.Get<int, float>();

    std::cout <<
        std::is_same<decltype(result), std::tuple<int, float>>::value
          << std::endl;

    int &i=std::get<0>(result);
    float &f=std::get<1>(result);

    std::cout << i << " " << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output, tested with gcc 6.3.1:

```
1
0 2
```

Comment: "The first matching type" is misleading. If the type occurs more than once, the program is ill-formed.